# confused with for loop incrementing rule

Tags: c, for-loop, increment

Can you tell me why the OUTPUT of this program is `ABBBCDE`?

It was my exam question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf ("A");
        for (; i < 3; i++)
        printf ("B");
        printf ("C");
        for (; i < 4; i++)
        printf ("D");
        printf ("E");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Informally speaking, without braces, the body of the `for` loop is the next line

Comment: It seems obvious to me, so it's hard to explain it. It would be easier to explain where you are wrong if you said what **you** thought the output should be.

Comment: Write `i = 0` on a piece of paper. Then go through the code line by line, adding the characters, and update the value you wrote down every time `i` is incremented.

Comment: Adam edited my code, thank you. This code makes sense now.

Comment: @Turuudo: Although it does somewhat change the question.  Why not edit the question to `int main(){printf("ABBBCDE");}`?

Comment: @Adam I reverted your edit. You should not “explain” the code by editing the question.

Comment: @Bathsheba - are you saying the accepted answer at the link you've provided is incorrect?

Comment: @Melebius - this is the only way to explain the code and the results he get.

Comment: @Adam No, you should write an answer to explain the code. Not make the question irrelevant by editing it.

Comment: @songyuanyao: In which case I think I'm going to hang up my tools for the day and head out for a nice long lunch. I learnt something new today. Funny I had this in my head that `int main(void)` was valid C but not valid C++

Comment: I'll clean up some of my comments.

Comment: @Bathsheba So you think them the opposite. Glad to know I'm not missing something. :)

Comment: @Adam I originally posted an answer in reponse to your edited version of the question, which in retrospect didn't make sense given what they'd originally asked. It was a waste of my time. The correct way to answer someone's question is to post an answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao: What I need to do is to re-read Stroustrup methinks.

Comment: This is solely C language code. I added C++ hash cause I thought my question would receive more popularity.

Comment: @ThomasSablik C++ provides both `stdio.h` and `cstdio`. Including `stdio.h` gives you `printf` in the global namespace while `cstdio` gives you `printf` in the `std` namespace (and it's implementation defined whether it also gives it in the global namespace). So it is technically valid C++. Having said that, it's certainly also valid C and I agree it was probably targeted at C.

Comment: @Turuudo Please do not use unrelated tags, especially not to receive more popularity – this is a clear misuse! Tags are used to specify what the question is about. If you use the C++ tag for a C question, you might get a C++ answer that won’t work in C.

Comment: @Melebius Okay, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a for loop that checks if i is less than three. It starts at zero, zero is less than three so it prints B once, then it adds one to i and i becomes one, which is still less than three, so it prints another B. Then it ads one to i, making it two, which is still less than zero, which makes it print B a third time. Then it adds another one to i, making it three, which is not less than three, so it continues the program by typing C.

Answer (score 5):

```
int
main (void)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      printf ("A");
      for (; i < 3; i++)
      printf ("B");
      printf ("C");
      for (; i < 4; i++)
      printf ("D");
      printf ("E");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

is the same as

```
int
main (void)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      printf ("A"); // prints once
      for (; i < 3; i++)
      {
          printf ("B"); // i = 0 at beginning, and loops until i = 2 => 3 times
      }
      printf ("C"); // prints once
      for (; i < 4; i++) 
      {
          printf ("D"); // i = 3 at beginning, so it prints once
      }
      printf ("E"); // prints once
    } // next loop, i is already 4, which is more than 2, so first loop stops
  return 0;
}
```

Please don't write like this for production code.

Answer (score 3):

If you indent the code properly it will help you understand what's going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("A");        // prints A 1 time, i is still 0
        for (; i < 3; i++)  // prints B 3 times, i will now be 3, the cycle ends
            printf("B");  
        printf("C");        // prints C 1 time, this is not in any inner loop
        for (; i < 4; i++)  // prints D once, as i is 3, the cycle only runs once
            printf("D");
        printf("E");        // again prints E once
    }                       // as i is 4 the cycle will end, the condition is i < 2
    return 0;              
}
```